# Xamarin Webview memory issue?

Tags: android, webview, garbage-collection, xamarin.forms

I'm both trying to figure out the xamarin profiler and find memory issues in my app.  To do this I created a simple 3 page app:

- On startup the app assigns to MainPage a new NavigationPage (new Page1)
- Page1 has 3 buttons, one to push page 2, one to push page 3, one to run the garbage collector
- Page2 has a button that pops it from the navigation stack, and a WebView
- Page3 has a button to set the Application's MainPage to a new NavigationPage(new Page1)

I tap the buttons to push/pop page2 5 times then take a snap shot - I have 5 instances of Page2, WebView, WebViewRenderer, and WebClient.

Then I tap the GC button.  Now there is only 1 instance of Page2 and WebView, but still 5 WebViewRenderer and WebClient.  Why weren't these garbage collected?
[image]

Then tap Page3 and the new MainPage button, then the GC button.  Now all but one instance of WebViewRenderer and WebClient are removed.
[image]

Does this indicate a memory leak with webviews?

Comment: I don't think there is enough data here to determine that. Are you hooking into any event handlers? And do you unhook them when you do not need them anymore?

Comment: No, I am not hooking into event handlers or even loading anything into the webview.  All I added to the page was the web view definition - <WebView></WebView> - and the page itself does get picked up by the GC, it is only the android WebViewRenderer and WebClient that persist.  I did test with adding Content = null in the page's OnDisapearing event with no change.